# How to change myadress.php in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to edit some of my account files. For example the my-adress.php. I override it by copy and pasting the my-address.php file to

```
/domains/domainname/public_html/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/woocommerce/myaccount.
```

But the changes won’t be visible. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You've copied and followed the way you need to override templates. Hope you haven't renamed file and copied to woocommerce/myaccount folder.

Please also check your theme's functions.php or other file that has added

`add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );`

into after_theme_setup action.

If you couldn't found above code to be added into your theme

add it into functions.php

`function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );`

Hope this helps you!